# Uncovering Formatting?

Tags: beamer, formatting

Is there any way to have a slide show a block of text, and then by some `\uncover` type command, bold or underline a certain part of that text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `\only`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\strut Some \only<1>{test text}\only<2>{\ul{test text}} goes here.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Change `\ul{<text>}` to `\textbf{<text>}` for boldface.

If you are interested in highlighting some text, then the `alert` specification, together with `\action` is useful here:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some \action<1-|alert@2>{test text} goes here.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```